# Why is it necessary to allocate memory for buffer when it is created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Javascript being a dynamic language, why is it mandatory to mention the size of the buffer when it is created?

```
var buffer = new Buffer(10);
```

Comment: check https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html the first example + comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should think it's likely that `Buffer` instances use [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) behind the scenes for efficiency, or even low-level arrays (as `Buffer` is a native part of Node, which is written in C++, not JavaScript). Indeed, looking at [`node_buffer.cc`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_buffer.cc), that appears to be the case. Typed arrays or low-level arrays are fixed-size, allocate-on-creation structures.

---

Side note: `new Buffer(size)` is deprecated; use [`Buffer.alloc`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_alloc_size_fill_encoding) instead.

Answer (score 2):

From Node.js documentation :

> Instances of the Buffer class are similar to arrays of integers but
>   correspond to fixed-sized, raw memory allocations outside the V8 heap.
>   The size of the Buffer is established when it is created and cannot be
>   resized.

Since arrays themselves need that their size be specified at initialization hence similarly for Buffer.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a buffer in a programming language, you are essentially setting aside a specific amount of memory to store data. This memory allocation is necessary for several reasons:

- Reserved Space
- Contiguous Memory
- Preventing Overflows
- Dynamic Size
- Proper Initialization
- Resource Management